# How to find the exact class by CSS Selector in selenium python?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, automation, css-selectors

I want to get all class named = "panel-content" only, so i have done this:

```
driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("div.panel-content")
```

but it also selects the class named = "accordion-table panel-content", as it has "panel-content" string in it's name.
but what i want is only "panel-content" class.how to do that?

Comment: Can you show us what the html looks like? You'll have to find a unique selector. In the firefox devtools you can `right-click` -> `copy` -> `css selector` to copy the exact css selector for an element, maybe this helps.

Comment: Can you explain that further? If some element has the raw class string `accordion-table panel-content`, that means that this element has both the class `accordion-table` and `panel-content`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

Here you go:

CSS selector:

```
[class='panel-content']
```

Locator:

```
driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("[class='panel-content']")
```

Comment: This is not a good way or a CSS-like way to do this. You have basically reduced the class name check to a string match. If any other class gets added to this element, this will fail.

Comment: By request he wanted "all class named = "panel-content""